# Unable to run JFrame in Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, hibernate, maven

I try to run a `JFrame` (.java) in Eclipse as a Java application, but the Console gives me this output:

```
Usage: javaw [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
   or  javaw [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
-server   to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is server.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

It is a Maven project. I have installed:

- Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
- JDK 8 Update 91 (64-bit)

Comment: The console in Eclipse is giving that output?

Comment: Yes, the 'Console' tab, right beneath the code, in red lettering.

Comment: title cleaned: no need for Eclipse as you've got an [tag:eclipse] tag, and certainly no need for "I'm desperate"